# Question about enumeration

Tags: listings, lists, enumerate

I need to use an enumeration inside another one without using two enumeration-environments one inside the other. I have tried the command \subitem but it seems it doesn't exist. Which command should I use?

Comment: `\newlist` allows nested lists.

Comment: why can't you use two enumerate environments, that would be the standard syntax

Comment: That's the problem! Because I'm using the Beamer package and I have to put an enumeration before the \begin{frame} command and a sub-enumeration after it but I have to continue the sub-enumeration also in the next frame and I don't manage to do it because if I don't close the sub-enumeration before the \end{frame} command it gives me error.

Comment: beamer lists are completely different, if you wanted an answer that worked with beamer you should really mention beamer.   Also (especially given your (weird?) interleaving with frames it is best to always provide a complete small test document that shows the problem.